# Controller Spec 'Check model Validations'

Tags: validation, rspec

All of my contracts_controller_spec.rb tests are passing except for one.

It fails with this:

```
 ContractsController #create redirects to show page when given valid params.
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns[:contract].valid?).to be_true    # factory is missing
 # code_id and maybe others, check model validations
   expected: true value
        got: false
```

Here is my model:

```
 class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employee
   belongs_to :client
   belongs_to :primary_care_manager
   belongs_to :code
   has_many :schedules


   attr_accessible :authorization_number, :start_date, :end_date, :client_id,
   :units, :contracted_units, :frequency, :code_id, :primary_care_manager_id,
   :employee_id, :employee_flag

   validates_presence_of :authorization_number, :start_date, :end_date,
   :units, :contracted_units, :frequency, :code_id

   validates_presence_of :client_id, :primary_care_manager_id, unless: Proc.new { |a|
   a.employee_flag }
   validates_presence_of :employee_id, if: Proc.new { |a| a.employee_flag }
```

and here is the example in my contracts_controller_spec.rb test that fails:

```
  it "#create redirects to show page when given valid params." do
    contract = attributes_for(:contract)
    post :create, contract: contract
    expect(assigns[:contract]).to be_a Contract
    expect(assigns[:contract].valid?).to be_true    # factory is missing code_id and maybe
            # others, check model validations
    expect(response).to be_redirect
    expect(response).to redirect_to contract_path(id: assigns[:contract].id)
  end
```

lastly, here is my factory.rb file

```
   factory :contract do
     association :employee,              factory: :employee
     association :client,                factory: :client
     association :code,                  factory: :code
     association :primary_care_manager,  factory: :primary_care_manager
     sequence(:authorization_number)     { |n| "20007000-#{'%03d' % n}" }
     start_date                          Date.today
     end_date                            Date.today.next_month
     units                               "15 minutes"
     contracted_units                    "20"
     frequency                           "weekly"
     employee_flag                       true
   end
```

I did check the tail.test.log and saw that while the foreign keys are created they are not available at the time that the this example is run:

```
  it "#create redirects to show page when given valid params." do
```

Can someone please help me to understand how to write this test such that I get the timing to work such that the foreign keys show up when I run the above example in my controller test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `attributes_for` doesn't allocate ids for the associated factories. `Factory.build` on the other hand does allocate ids for associated factories.

So you can do something like:

```
contract = Factory.build(:contract).attribues.symbolize_keys
```

instead of:

```
contract = attributes_for(:contract)
```

However there is a downside to using `build` with associations. In order to generate the id of the associated objects FactoryGirl creates the associated objects, so although `build` doesn't generally hit the database in this case it will insert a record for each association. If that matters to you then you might want to check out the newer `build_stubbed` method, see http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/22670085288/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test .

Comment: Thanks @steve ... I will check out the 'newer build_stubbed' method.